# How to enable SMB2 on Synology DS508

Tags: linux, samba, smb2, ipkg

I have a Synology DS508 box. It is running latest Synology DSM 4.0 with ipkg installed.

Recently I've upgraded my Mac to Maverics, and I want to switch from using AFP to access my shares on Synology to SMB2 in hopes that it may get faster.

However, SMB2 is only supported only starting from DSM 4.2 and is really useful from 4.3. Synology DS508 only supports DSM 4.0.

Is there a way I can get SMB2 working on my DS508 box? I guess I can upgrade samba myself, using ipkg, but I hesitate to do this without a guide — which I failed to google up.

Any hints?

Answer (score -1):

There is a simple script that you can run in "Terminal" to make SMB1 the default.

echo "[default]" >> ~/Library/Preferences/nsmb.conf; echo "smb_neg=smb1_only" >> ~/Library/Preferences/nsmb.conf

You can just cut and paste thuis into a terminal window and execute.  It worked for me.

Comment: I probably am missing something. How this should help me to enable SMB2?